# Are there MATLAB scripts that will give me a quantitative/visual depiction of all the colors in an image?

Tags: image, matlab, colors

I have tried the following:

```
b=imread('/home2/s163720/lebron.jpg');
hsv = rgb2hsv(b);
h = hsv(:,:,1);
imhist(h,16)
```

However, it does not give me quite what I'm looking for. It would be great to see a counter of some sort for different hues, or maybe even a distribution of the colors. 
This would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're only using 16 bins? I'm not sure what you want to get out of this, but `imhist` already displays a plot of the number of pixels in each of the bins (hues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be on the line of what you're looking for.

```
%Read the image
img = imread('/home2/s163720/lebron.jpg');

%convert to hsv and reshap to a N x 3 matrix
hsv = rgb2hsv(img);
hsv2 = squeeze(reshape(hsv, [], 1, 3));

%Extract hue (and convert to an angle) and saturation
Hue = 2*pi*hsv2(:,1);
Saturation = hsv2(:,2);

%The number of bins in the hue and saturation directions
RadialColorBins = 50;
AngularColorBins = 50;

%Where the edged of the bins are
edges = {linspace(0, 1, RadialColorBins), linspace(0, 2*pi, AngularColorBins) - 2*pi / AngularColorBins};

%bin the data
[heights,centers] = hist3([Saturation, Hue],'Edges',edges);

%Extract the centers
radius = centers{1};
angle = centers{2};

%Force periodicity
angle = [angle, angle(1)];
heights = [heights, heights(:, 1)]';

%Mesh the r and theta components
[Radius, Angle] = meshgrid(radius, angle);

%Make a color map for the polar plot
CMap = hsv2rgb(Angle/(2*pi), Radius, ones(size(Radius)));

figure(1)
imshow(img)

%polar histogram in s-h space
figure(2)
surf(Radius.*cos(Angle), Radius.*sin(Angle), heights, CMap,'EdgeColor','none');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is supposed to be where the answers should be, but I am quite sure that there is not a generic answer for your question. However there are a couple of possibilities, maybe you or anyone else can come up with more.

So the basic problem as you want a histogram, is that you have to choose some representation of the color as a single number. Which is quite a difficult problem.

The first solution could be to transform the rgb color to wavelength, and then ignore the intensity of the image. The problem by using this idea is that the rgb colors defines more colors than on wavelength alone. see: http://jp.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/313712

A second solution could be to define a number as A = sum(rgb.*[1,10,100]); and then use this number as your representation of the color.

A third solution would be to transform the hexadecimal representation of the number to a decimal representation and then use this number.

Once you have a representation for every color of every pixel, you simply reshape the matrix into a vector and use the standard hist command to plot it. But as mentioned, mayby someone has a better idea for a representation of the color as a single number.